# Perl using XML Path Context to extract out data

Tags: perl, xml-parsing, xml-libxml

I have the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
   <Function Name="GetSomethingById">
      <something idSome="1" Code="1" Description="TEST01" LEFT="0" RIGHT="750" />
   </Function>
</Response>
```

and I want the attributes of `<something>` node as a hash. Im trying like below

```
my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new(
    XML::LibXML->new()->parse_string($xml)   # $xml is containing the above xml
);
my @nodes = $xpc->findnodes('/Response/Function/something');
```

Im expecting to have something like `$nodes[0]->getAttributes`, any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
my %attributes = map { $_->name => $_->value } $node->attributes();
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :) thnx a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Your XPATH query seems to be wrong - you are searching for `'/WSApiResponse/Function/something'` while the root node of your XML is `Response` and not `WSApiResponse`

From the docs of [`XML::LibXML::Node`](http://search.cpan.org/~phish/XML-LibXML-1.53/lib/XML/LibXML/Node.pod) (the kind of stuff that `findnodes()` is expected to return), you should look for `my $attrs = $nodes[0]->attributes()` instead of `$nodes[0]->getAttributes`

Comment: ah.. sorry it was a typo while copy and paste... extremely sorry to confuse you.

Answer (score 0):

I use [`XML::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm) for this type of thing. So if the XML file is `data.xml`

```
use strict;
use XML::Simple();
use Data::Dumper();

my $xml = XML::Simple::XMLin( "data.xml" );
print Data::Dumper::Dumper($xml);
my $href = $xml->{Function}->{something};
print Data::Dumper::Dumper($href);
```

Note: With XML::Simple the root tag maps to the result hash itself. Thus there is no `$xml->{Response}`

Comment: Me too. XML::Simple is the way to go.

Comment: Why do you think there can only be one `Function`? XML::Simple is the most complicated XML module there is.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... However, the solution from @ikegami was exactly what I need.